# SQL Server: Remove hyphens in the start and end of string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to concatenate from 7 different columns of a table with hyphen between text from each column.

In few cases  where columns have nulls,
I get string like; `--Account--stands---`

The desired output is `Account-stands`. Please help.

Regards,
Sajan

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What did you try so far? Have a look at this guide: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to include a sample code to show your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can do:

```
select stuff(coalesce('-' + col1, '') +
             coalesce('-' + col2, '') +
             coalesce('-' + col3, '') +
             coalesce('-' + col4, '') +
             coalesce('-' + col5, '') +
             coalesce('-' + col6, '') +
             coalesce('-' + col7, ''),
              1, 1, '')
```

Many other databases support a function like `CONCAT_WS()` that simplifies this operation.

Comment: This will throw syntax error, remove `(` before each `coalesce`.

Comment: The pitfalls of copy & paste, I'm sure :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve It by using `COALESCE` and `STUFF` and to avoid issues with blank values `''` you could add `NULLIF` in following

```
select stuff( coalesce(nullif('-' + col1, '-'), '') +
              coalesce(nullif('-' + col2, '-'), '') +
              coalesce(nullif('-' + col3, '-'), '') +
              coalesce(nullif('-' + col4, '-'), '') +
              coalesce(nullif('-' + col5, '-'), '') +
              coalesce(nullif('-' + col6, '-'), '') +
              coalesce(nullif('-' + col7, '-'), ''),
              1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you could use `CASE` expression to check whether the value is `null` or not.

**Query**

```
select case when t.[concat_string] like '%-' 
then left(t.[concat_string], len(t.[concat_string]) - 1) 
else t.[concat_string] end as [concat_string] from(
    select 
    case when [col1] is null or ltrim(rtrim([col1])) = '' 
         then '' else [col1] + '-' end + 
    case when [col2] is null or ltrim(rtrim([col2])) = '' 
         then '' else [col2] + '-' end + 
    case when [col3] is null or ltrim(rtrim([col3])) = '' 
         then '' else [col3] + '-' end + 
    case when [col4] is null or ltrim(rtrim([col4])) = '' 
         then '' else [col4] + '-' end + 
    case when [col5] is null or ltrim(rtrim([col5])) = '' 
         then '' else [col5] + '-' end + 
    case when [col6] is null or ltrim(rtrim([col6])) = '' 
         then '' else [col6] + '-' end + 
    case when [col7] is null or ltrim(rtrim([col7])) = '' 
         then '' else [col7] end as [concat_string]
    from [your_table_name]
)t;
```

And if any of the columns are not `VARCHAR`, then you may need to `CAST` it to `VARCHAR`

Comment: So complex syntax, really more readable way is to achieve It using `STUFF` and `COALESCE`.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas : `COALESCE` doesn't help if the value is not null but `''`. And let my answer be there as an another perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have build your query like the below one.

```
select 
isnull(col1,'') + '-' + isnull(col2,'') + '-' + isnull(col3,'') as [columns]
from yourtable
```

Replace the null value with a character. For example try the below query

```
        select replace(replace ([columns],'|-',''), (case when 
charindex ('-|',replace ([columns],'|-','')) > 0 then '-|' else '|' end),'') 
    from(select 
        isnull(col1,'|') + '-' + isnull(col2,'|') + '-' +isnull(col3,'|')[columns]
        from yourtable)temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @String table (String nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @String
SELECT '--Account--stands---'

;WITH Cte
AS
(
SELECT String From
(
SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String,
PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%',Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) AS ISChar FROM
(
SELECT 
 CAST( '<S>' + REPLACE(STRING ,'--','</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS String  from @String
 ) AS A
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)

) dt
Where dt.ISChar=1
)
SELECT DISTINCT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '- ' + String  FROM Cte
FOr xml path ('')),1,1,'') AS String
FROM Cte
```

OutPut

```
String
-------
 Account- stands
```